# Grails - passing domain classes between controllers

Tags: grails, controller

In my Grails application, I have created a User class. In one controller, I query the database to confirm that the information a user has given is valid. Then, I would like to pass that User object to another controller to do some more processing on it. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: You should be using a service

Comment: tim_yates you should expand on that a bit and make it an answer.

Comment: And I'm not sure what you mean by 'passing a domain object to a different controller'. Controllers don't invoke controllers, controllers are invoked by the framework as a result of a http request...

Answer (score 1):

For your question on passing objects between controllers, if you are using a `redirect` or a `forward` you can add objects in the param map:

```
redirect(action: "actionName", user: userInstance)
```

or

```
forward(action: "actionName", user: userInstance)
```

Another solution would be to store the user in the `flash` object (a temporary storage map cleared after the next request) or `session`:

```
flash.user = userInstance
```

or

```
session.user = userInstance
```

But in your case, as stated by tim_yates, you should create a service to handle the User entity.
To do so execute the command:

```
create-service com.package.user
```

Then add all the processing you are doing on a User in the newly created class and inject the User service in your controller like this:

```
def controller{

    def userService

    def action(){
        userService.validate(...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentaily what  @tim_yates was getting at was the logic for all of your controllers should be in services. Then any action in any controller can execute that logic without redirecting/forwarding a request. This also is the way it should be due to the transactional nature of services.